# Printing the content of a HashSet MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So i have my function that generates pdf in my controller.However , i am not able to print the collection in the pdf as it is giving me System.Collections.Generic.HashSet
I want to print the content of the hashset.Any ideas to solve this?

```
private static byte[] GeneratePdf(List<Plant> plants)
    {
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var doc = new Document())
            {
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, memoryStream);

                doc.Open();
                doc.SetMargins(120, 120, 270, 270);
                BaseFont font = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, false);
                Font normalFont = new Font(font, 12, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);





                Paragraph pgTitle = new Paragraph();
                pgTitle.Font = new Font(font, 20, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK); 
                pgTitle.Add("American University of Beirut");
                doc.Add(pgTitle);

                Paragraph pgPlantTitle = new Paragraph();

                pgPlantTitle.Font = new Font(font, 18, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
                pgPlantTitle.Add("Plant Description");
                doc.Add(pgPlantTitle);

                foreach (Plant p in plants)
                {
                    Paragraph plantDisc = new Paragraph();

                    plantDisc.Font = new Font(font, 14, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
                    plantDisc.Add(new Paragraph(" "));
                    plantDisc.Add(new Paragraph(" "));
                    plantDisc.Add("Plant Name :");

                    plantDisc.Add(p.ScientificName);
                    plantDisc.Add(new Paragraph(" "));
                    plantDisc.Add("Plant Type :");
                    plantDisc.Add(new Paragraph(" "));
                    plantDisc.Add(p.TypeOfPlants.ToString());

                    plantDisc.Add("Plant Height Range :");
                    plantDisc.Add(new Paragraph(" "));
                    plantDisc.Add("Plant Spread Range :");
                    plantDisc.Add(new Paragraph(" "));
                    plantDisc.Add("Tree Shape :");
                    plantDisc.Add(new Paragraph(" "));
                    plantDisc.Add("Plant Origin :");
                    plantDisc.Add(new Paragraph(" "));
                    plantDisc.Add("Plant Color :");
                    plantDisc.Add(new Paragraph(" "));
                    plantDisc.Add("Fruit Color :");
                    plantDisc.Add(new Paragraph(" "));
                    plantDisc.Add("Light Requirement :");
                    List<string> list = p.LightRequirements.Select(z => z.ToString()).ToList();
                    plantDisc.Add(list.ToString());
                    plantDisc.Add(new Paragraph(" "));
                    plantDisc.Add("Water Requirement :");


                    doc.Add(plantDisc);

                    doc.Add(new Paragraph(" "));

                }

            }
            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is really a bad title. Please put a specific title based on your problem. 
[How do I write a good title?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/158761)

Comment: I Changed the title!Is it good?

Comment: Are you getting another exception message that could be useful? Please add that as well

Comment: No at the pdf as it opens it doesn't print the content of the hashset it only prints System.Collections.Generic.HashSet which is the name.It prints the name not the content of the hash set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't work out from your code where the Hast Set is, but if you are doing .ToString() on the set all you will get is the type:

```
var mySet = new HashSet<string>();
mySet.Add("Lorem");
mySet.Add("Ipsum");

System.Console.WriteLine(mySet.ToString());

// OUTPUTS: System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[System.String]
```

You need to do something like:

```
foreach (var thing in mySet)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(thing);
}

// OUTPUTS: Lorem 
//          Ipsum
```

You can run this as a [.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sq0qTb) to see what I mean.

Depending on how you want to output things, you can potentially do something neater like a Linq [.Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb548651(v=vs.100).aspx) command.